# Somar ou subtrair valor, conforme for o "tipo de lançamento" (MSSQL)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 
ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE, 
PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO, 
TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO,
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA,  
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO, 
SUM(QTDEKG) AS SALDO_KG
FROM MOVTIPOPRODUTO 
INNER JOIN PRODUTO ON PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO 
INNER JOIN TIPOPRODUTO ON TIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO 
LEFT JOIN ENTIDADE ON ENTIDADE.ID_CLIENTE = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE 
LEFT JOIN PESAGEM ON PESAGEM.REFERENCIA = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.REFERENCIA 
WHERE (MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE > 0) 
AND ISNULL(MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 0) = 88
AND MOVTIPOPRODUTO.CANCELADO = 0 
GROUP BY 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE, 
PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO, 
TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO, 
ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO
ORDER BY PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO
```

E preciso que dependendo do `TIPOLCTO` o valor `(SUM(QTDEKG) AS SALDO_KG)` seja subtraído ao invés de somado. 
Ex:

- Se `TIPOLCTO = 1`, ele deve somar
- Se `TIPOLCTO = 2`, ele deve subtrair
- Se `TIPOLCTO = 3`, ele deve subtrair (também)
- Se `TIPOLCTO = 0`, ele deve ignorar o valor

Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo entender como ele vai fazer isso

Hoje esta me retornando o seguinte resultado:

```
ID  NOME            PROD.   TIPO PROD.      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 TIPOLCTO    SALDO_KG
88  NOME DO CLIENTE SOJA    SOJA INTACTA    1   3   3   1   4           1243997,496
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 1    3   4   1   1   4           800265,21
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 1    3   4   2   1   4           780134,434
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 2    3   5   1   1   4           438133,43
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 2    3   5   2   1   4           71170,524
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 3    3   6   1   1   2           570,00
88  NOME DO CLIENTE TRIGO   TRIGO TIPO 3    3   6   1   1   4           65413,94
```

Hoje estou listando essa tabela em uma table em PHP, obrigado desde já!

Comment: e quando for `4` (como na maioria das linhas)?

Comment: Ele vai subtrair também, porque o tipo de lançamento no caso significa se o valor deu entrada, saída, transferência interna ou externa o que também seria subtração no caso! Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` para fazer o que deseja!

Com ele você pode condicionar o campo de valor com a característica que você quiser (negativo, positivo, zerado...) e depois somar tudo.

**Condições para o campo `MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO`:**

```
 case
    when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 1 then
     QTDEKG
    when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO in (2, 3) then
     QTDEKG * -1
    when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 0 then
     0
    --pode ainda acrescentar else para outros valores

 end SALDO_KG
```

**SQL Completa:**

```
select ID_ENTIDADE,
       NOMECLIENTE,
       NOMEPRODUTO,
       DESCRICAO,
       ID_PRODUTO,
       ID_TIPOPRODUTO,
       ID_SAFRA,
       ID_LOCALESTOQUE,
       TIPOLCTO,
       sum(SALDO_KG) as SALDO_KG
  from (select MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE,
               ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE,
               PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO,
               TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO,
               MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO,
               MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO,
               MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA,
               MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE,
               MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO,
               --sum(QTDEKG) as SALDO_KG
               case
                  when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 1 then
                   QTDEKG
                  when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO in (2, 3) then
                   QTDEKG * -1
                  when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 0 then
                   0
               end SALDO_KG
          from MOVTIPOPRODUTO
         inner join PRODUTO on PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
         inner join TIPOPRODUTO on TIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO
          left join ENTIDADE on ENTIDADE.ID_CLIENTE = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE
          left join PESAGEM on PESAGEM.REFERENCIA = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.REFERENCIA
         where (MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE > 0)
           and ISNULL(MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 0) = 88
           and MOVTIPOPRODUTO.CANCELADO = 0)
 group by ID_ENTIDADE,
          NOMECLIENTE,
          NOMEPRODUTO,
          DESCRICAO,
          ID_PRODUTO,
          ID_TIPOPRODUTO,
          ID_SAFRA,
          ID_LOCALESTOQUE,
          TIPOLCTO
 order by NOMEPRODUTO
```

**Simplificando (sem SubQuery), dentro do próprio `SUM()`:**

```
select MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE,
       ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE,
       PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO,
       TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO,
       MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO,
       MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO,
       MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA,
       MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE,
       MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO,
       --SUM(QTDEKG) AS SALDO_KG
       sum(case
              when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 1 then
               QTDEKG
              when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO in (2, 3) then
               QTDEKG * -1
              when MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO = 0 then
               0
           end) SALDO_KG
  from MOVTIPOPRODUTO
 inner join PRODUTO on PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
 inner join TIPOPRODUTO on TIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO
  left join ENTIDADE on ENTIDADE.ID_CLIENTE = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE
  left join PESAGEM on PESAGEM.REFERENCIA = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.REFERENCIA
 where (MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE > 0)
   and ISNULL(MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 0) = 88
   and MOVTIPOPRODUTO.CANCELADO = 0
 group by MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO,
          MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO,
          MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA,
          MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE,
          MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE,
          PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO,
          TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO,
          ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE,
          MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO
 order by PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO
```

Comment: Só não entendi o motivo do `sub-select`.

Comment: Não é necessário! Mas para entendimento é melhor... Pode ser alterado tranquilamente dentro do `SUM()`

Comment: Muito obrigado Melissa, funcionou perfeitamente o sem SubQuery! Estava desde sexta me batendo nisso! Grande abraço! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 
ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE, 
PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO, 
TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO,
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA,  
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO, 
CASE 
WHEN TIPOLCTO = 2
THEN 
   SUM(QTDEKG * -1)
ELSE 
  SUM(QTDEKG)
END 
AS SALDO_KG
FROM MOVTIPOPRODUTO 
INNER JOIN PRODUTO ON PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO 
INNER JOIN TIPOPRODUTO ON TIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO 
LEFT JOIN ENTIDADE ON ENTIDADE.ID_CLIENTE = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE 
LEFT JOIN PESAGEM ON PESAGEM.REFERENCIA = MOVTIPOPRODUTO.REFERENCIA 
WHERE (MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE > 0) 
AND ISNULL(MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 0) = 88
AND MOVTIPOPRODUTO.CANCELADO = 0 
GROUP BY 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_TIPOPRODUTO, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_SAFRA, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_ENTIDADE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.ID_LOCALESTOQUE, 
PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO, 
TIPOPRODUTO.DESCRICAO, 
ENTIDADE.NOMECLIENTE, 
MOVTIPOPRODUTO.TIPOLCTO
ORDER BY PRODUTO.NOMEPRODUTO
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!